# How to pass arguments to promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I've go a small angular app with directive.
For retriving data from serverside I use ngRoute. After retriving data I bind result to a scope property and parse the result with ng-repeat like so:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="clsRow in classificatorData">
   <span>{{clsRow.code}}</span>
 </div>
```

This function that retrievs data from resource

```
var getClassificatorDataScope = function (criteria, predicate) {
                references.initialize('classificators');
                references
                    .getRefereces(null, $scope.classificatorType, criteria, predicate == null ? "NONE" : predicate, $scope.limitLevel, null)
                    .$promise.then(function (result) {
                        $scope.classificatorData = result.Data;
                    });


            };
```

Everything works fine. But if I try to implement passing result data container (dataScope) like so

```
var getClassificatorDataScope = function (criteria, predicate, dataScope) {
                references.initialize('classificators');
                references
                    .getRefereces(null, $scope.classificatorType, criteria, predicate == null ? "NONE" : predicate, $scope.limitLevel, null)
                    .$promise.then(function (result) {
                        dataScope = result.Data;
                    });


            };
```

And use it in controller like so

```
getClassificatorDataScope("CODE", null, $scope.classificatorData);
```

I've got no data at all. Please help me to understand such behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 problems here.

```
dataScope = result.Data;
```

The first one is this. This doesn't act like how you'd expect it would. *It doesn't replace the `$scope.classificatorData`*. All it does is replace the local `dataScope` variable in `getClassificatorDataScope` to `result.Data` (yes, it's not "passed by reference").

Second, you're using promises incorrectly. You *return the promise* for listening, not pass the scope to who-knows-where. Your data layer should not be aware of `$scope` or the UI in general. Return the promise to the controller, and have it listen for the data from it.

```
// In your function
var getClassificatorDataScope = function(criteria, predicate) {
  references.initialize('classificators');
  return references
    .getRefereces(null, $scope.classificatorType, criteria, predicate == null ? "NONE" : predicate, $scope.limitLevel, null)
    .$promise
};

// In your controller
getClassificatorDataScope("CODE", null).then(function(result){
  $scope.classificatorData = result.Data;
});
```

Comment: Dear Joseph. Could you explain why  - it's not "pass the reference"? I thought clouser would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your references.getRefereces method. It should return a promise and later resolve it with the proper result(I see you try to access "Data" attribute from result.). something like this:

```
reference.getReferences = function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();  
       someAsyncOperations(function callback(){
          deferred.resolve({Data: result})  // make sure you have the "Data" attr
       })
       return deferred.promise;

// or if someAyncOperations already return a promise
// return someAsyncOperations.then(function(result) {
//    return {Data: result};
// });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in second example you're trying to assign data retrieved from server to `dataScope` but since AJAX data loading is asynchronoys so `$promise` is resolved later than your template with `ng-repeat` is drawn.

There's not enough code provided in question to write whole example - how it should be implemented. But basically you should return `$promise` from your service and in controller change $scope variables upon

```
promise.then(function() {
//do stuff with $scope variables
})
```